# importing a module that imports the main module

Tags: python, import, module, circular-dependency

I'm working on a text adventure that stores the levels as a massive dictionary called 'places'. Instead of having it in the main file, I thought that I would make a separate file called 'levels.py' that would contain it, making my code cleaner and eliminating the need to go through 450+ lines of other code to add to it.

So, the main game file:

```
from levels import places

class Thing:
    #Some stuff
```

levels.py:

```
from game import *
places = {
    "bleh" : Thing("bleh"),
}
```

It seems like 'places' isn't defined in the game, however.

I think that what's happening is that there's an import 'loop'. However, if levels.py needs to import classes from game.py, how could I prevent something like that?

Comment: You can't have a circular dependency. Split your modules properly.

Comment: Well, you *can*, but it's a bad idea.

Comment: my classes also require the places dictionary.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's always possible to *refactor* to eliminate circular dependencies.  Move `Thing` to `thing.py`, then in `game.py` and in `levels.py` use `from thing import Thing`.  Rinse and repeat.

Comment: Thanks, but since I have a whole lot of classes I just put them all in a new file called 'classes.py' and had both files import that. Also, that makes game.py have way more of the actual gameplay and less class definitions.

Comment: @Cheezey, `import game \\...\\ "bleh": game.Thing("bleh")`

Answer (score 0):

You could change `levels` to have an initializer or factory method that takes an object provided by `game`.

For example:

```
# levels.py
# no import needed here; we'll just take an instance when required
def get_places(thing):
    return {"bleh": thing("bleh")}
```

```
# game.py

import levels

class Thing:
    def __init__(self):
        self.places = levels.get_places(self)
```

**Edit:**

Even better would be to move the data that both classes need into another class that they can both easily access or import.  Like a game state object, for example, that gets passed around between classes with functionality.